Prove there’s infinitely many primes of the form 3n+2
Prove that there’s infinitely many primes of the form $3n+2$ by considering numbers of the form $3p_1 … p_k -1$.
(I’ve seen a similar question on here, but not using the form given).
Obviously I assumed finitely many of the form (listed $p_1,…,p_k$). Then defined $P=3p_1 … p_k -1$, and so all prime factors of $P$ must have the form $3n+1$. I was then looking for a contradiction, but I couldn’t seem to find one.

@openspace it’s a proof of the same situation, but I’ve been specifically asked to consider a number in the form, and I don’t think any of the answers to that question use that form

Maybe that hint was misleading? Where is it from?

Does this answer your question? Are there infinitely many primes numbers for congruece class 0,1,2 mod 3 - found using an Approach0 search. Note that Joffan's answer specifically uses numbers of the form $3p_1\ldots p_k-1$ you requested.

The contradiction arises in the following way
Lemma: any number of the form 3n-1 must have a prime factor of the form 3q-1
Proof of lemma:
P = 3n-1
let it not have any prime factor of the form 3q-1 , thus all prime factors are of the form 3q+1 , but this is not possible as then P will become $ (1)^xmod(3)$ but we know it is of the form 3n-1
Thus assumption must be wrong, thus we must have atleast one prime factor of the form 3q-1
Now , back to original proof , by lemma $$ P=3p_1 … p_k -1 $$ must have a prime factor of the form 3q-1 , but it is $\equiv (-1)mod(p_i)$ for all primes of the form 3q-1 , thus it itself must be prime , which contradicts the statement initially assumed ( $p_i$ are all such primes )
Any queries are highly encouraged. Thankyou!!
